# driver fails to install on Windows 8

Tags: driver-signing

I have an inf file and created a cat file running the following command:

inf2cat /v /driver:C:\Driver\ /os:XP_X86,Vista_X86,Vista_X64,7_X86,7_X64,8_X86,8_X64,6_3_X86,6_3_X64

Signed the cat file and created an .exe to test the driver. Driver is installed sucessfully in all os (I can see the driver in Control Panel) except Windows 8. Driver does not fail (I don't receive an error) but I cannot see it in Control Panel.

If I go back and create a cat file running the following command (only for Windows 8):

inf2cat /v /driver:C:\Driver\ /os:8_X86

and then sign the cat file and create an .exe to test the driver, driver is installed correctly in Windows 8 (I can see the driver in Control Panel).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I should mention here that if I open the cat file created for all os in OSAttr I am able to see 2:6.2 as well as the other os.

Comment: What part of the control panel are you looking in?  Could you provide the INF file, some information about the hardware the driver is talking to, and screenshots of the working and non-working control panels?  Is your device visible in the Device Manager if you do "View > Devices by Connection"?